# Drupal menu callback create node permissions

Tags: routes, users

I am creating a small menu, where I want to give access to a menu item when your are an authenticated user.

So I gave permission to authenticated users to create nodes of the type 'donation', but how would I formulate that in the menu acces arguments ?

```
$items['donate/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Donate',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('get_donate_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('create donation'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  user_is_logged_in() if you want only to check if the user is loged in
or you can use a custom function like

```
$items['donate/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Donate',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('get_donate_form'),
    'access arguments' => 'my_custom_permission',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

function my_custom_permission()
{

}
```

Comment: altough this gives me Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in menu_unserialize()

Comment: offcourse: it's access callback, not arguments :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use access arguments. Use [user_is_logged_in()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7) as access callback.